# SQL Server: convert string columns resulting from pivot into date time columns

Tags: sql-server, string, datetime, pivot

I started off with a SQL Server table that looks like this:

```
Id      cDate       parameter   oldValue         newValue
-----------------------------------------------------------------
96A11   10/17/2017  spanactual  10               9
96B15   10/17/2017  dtin        10/14/2017 0:00  10/15/2017 0:00
96B15   10/17/2017  dtout       11/20/2017 0:00  11/21/2017 0:00
0006F9A 10/19/2017  dtin        11/30/2017 0:00  12/1/2017 0:00
0006F9A 10/19/2017  dtout       12/1/2017 0:00   12/2/2017 0:00
```

Using the SQL code below I was able to pivot the table so that 'dtin' and 'dtout' parameters become columns.  (dtin and dtout dates are from the newValue column).

```
Select 
    Id, cDate,
    Min(Case parameter When 'dtin' Then newValue End) dtin,
    Min(Case parameter When 'dtout' Then newValue End) dtout
From 
    [scheduleChangeHistory]
Group By 
    Id, cDate
```

After running the above code my table now looks like this:

```
Id      cDate           dtin             dtout
-------------------------------------------------------
96A11   10/17/2017                       
96B15   10/17/2017      10/15/2017 0:00  11/21/2017 0:00
0006F9A 10/19/2017      12/1/2017 0:00   12/2/2017 0:00
```

The issue is my `dtin` and `dtout` are string columns and I need them to be `datetime` columns.

I cannot use temp tables in my SQL code. Therefore, is there a way to augment/add to my original SQL code so that the pivoted table produces columns `dtin` and `dtout` as `datetime` columns instead?

Comment: Put a `CONVERT( datetime, newValue )` in your `MIN` call.

Comment: where do I add that in?  I tried this: Min(CONVERT(datetime, newValue(Case parameter When 'dtin' Then newValue End) dtin)) but it will not run

Comment: No. Just around the `newValue`.  `Min(Case parameter When 'dtin' Then CONVERT( datetime, newValue ) End)`

Comment: it worked!  thank you :)